# How to capture the screen（include Mouse Cursor）in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to make a Application based on Mac OS X.That can broadcast one's screen images to the others，like in your laptop you can see what I am doing in my laptop.In the other words,it's like a real-time learning system.

now,my question is how can I continuously get the screen images,maybe 20 images per second.Then send this images to a multicast group.

So can you give me some advice(like using what object,what class in Objective-C)or provide some screen capture demos.

Sorry,my English is poor and I'm a new hand for Mac OS X programming.If you have something do not understand,please tell me.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.